# Can't seem to get sudo working under NixOS

Tags: nixos

The title (embarassing as it is) says it all. Some context first:

I'm running NixOS using a custom ISO on Vultr.

Timeframe of attempts:

- `which sudo` shows no sudo
- Installed `sudo` using `nix-env -i sudo`
- Then, when I tried to `sudo ...`, I see `sudo: /home/agam/.nix-profile/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
- `sudo su` didn't work for the same reason
- Okay, I uninstalled it (`nix-env --uninstall sudo`)
- Thought hmm, maybe I'm supposed to install it as root?
- So, `su` and then repeat the install
- Now when I try to `sudo ...`, I see `sudo: /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
  (so the same error as before, with a different path)
- As a last resort, try a hammer, and kudos to NixOS for stopping me:

```
[root@nixos:/home/agam]# chmod 4755 /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo
chmod: changing permissions of '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo': Read-only file system
```

Any clues on what's going on here?

Some possible options I see here are:
1. The custom ISO that Vultr provided was ... missing something
2. Some fundamentally different ways that `sudo` is supposed to work in NixOS
3. I'm missing something very basic in how to go about using Nix (most likely!)

Some details:

```
[agam@nixos:~]$ nixos-version
18.09.1534.d45a0d7a4f5 (Jellyfish)

[agam@nixos:~]$ which sudo
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo

[agam@nixos:~]$ nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09
```

*Edit*: final set of steps that worked:

1. As suggested in the answer, *enable* sudo first:

```
security.sudo.enable =  true;
```

2. Add a sudoers section to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
  # Allow members of the "wheel" group to sudo:
  security.sudo.configFile = ''
    %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
  '';
```

3. Add myself to `wheel`:

```
usermod -a -G wheel agam
```

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions. Try superuser.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. I saw a _lot_ of Nix/NixOS related questions on SO, so thought it would be fine, but I agree this is something that can be seen as a _sysadmin-y_ thing too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to install `sudo` on NixOS is by adding to `configuration.nix`:

```
security.sudo.enable = true;
```

Nix by itself is simply not capable of creating setuid binaries like sudo. Otherwise it could not be "safe and policy free" - no multi user support. The `nix`/`nix-`* tools are designed to perform safe store operations and not to allow elevation of privileges.

In order to support setuid binaries like `sudo`, NixOS maintains a directory of setuid wrappers outside the Nix store, in `/run/wrappers`. This is only possible because NixOS is started/switched/activated with root privileges.